# como preencher um campo de um site usando excel vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

[image]

Gostaria de saber como faço para preencher o campo.

Já tentei varias combinações para preencher o textbox destacado na foto, mas nada funciona.

Tentei coisas como:

```
IE.document.all("stk bs-Stake_TextBox").innerText = 1

IE.document.getElementsByClassName("stk bs-Stake_TextBox").Value = "5"

IE.document.getElementsByClassName("bs-Stake").Focus
```

código que tenho até o momento:

```
Sub CliqueEmBotaoBet365()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim oSelect As HTMLInputButtonElement
    IE.Visible = True

    'O ideal é que a pessoa pare o codigo aqui e navege manualmente, pois a bet365 nao vavega direito
    IE.navigate "https://www.bet365.com/#/AVR/B144/"

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 5)

    'Selecionar o 5º mercado dos esportes virtuais(Quando eu ja estava na pagina dos virtuais)
    IE.document.getElementsByClassName("vr-VirtualsNavBarButton_Label ")(4).Click

    'Seleciona a odd do 1º corredor
    IE.document.getElementsByClassName("vr-ParticipantVirtualOddsOnly_Odds")(0).Click

    'DEVERIA COLOCAR A APOSTA, MAS NAO FUNCIOBA
    IE.document.getElementsByClassName("bs-Stake") = "5"

'    IE.Quit
'    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Clebson seria possível colocar o link do site em questão? Ou tente

```
IE.document.all.Item("stk bs-Stake_TextBox").Value = "<valor desejado>"
```

Comment: Diz: A variável do objeto ou a variável do bloco 'with' não foi definida     o site é: https://www.bet365.com/#/AVR/B144/

Comment: Envie código ok?

Comment: O código é bem básico e ainda tem falhas, como por exemplo de navegação até o site...  Mesmo assim coloquei ele lá em cima. Só ta mal formatado pq não sei como formata aqui.

Comment: Então sem problemas, bom tira mais uma dúvida você quer eu ajude de forma completa, desde acessar o site com login/senha e depois tratar os dados? Faço sem problemas mas vamos conversando ok?

Comment: Ok... A principio eu queria só colocar a aposta, mas se vc tiver tempo e disposição pra me  ajudar com o resto, não irei recusar. Até pq levei um tempão pra conseguir clicar em um simples botão.

Comment: Ajudo sim, sem problemas. Vou fazer um cadastro e ver como são as telas depois.

Comment: podemos trocar numero de whatsapp por aqui?

Comment: não sei mas meu e-mail é auto autoeproject@gmail.com, ai trocamos por la ou conversamos via skype